# google app engine not able to get blob keys in production only

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine, blobstore

I have hit a snag that i can not seem to solve. My issue is with retrieving the blob key after the app engine has called my service back. I have tried using    `blobstoreService.getUploads(request)` and i have also tried pulling the blob key from the input stream on the request that is called back to me.

the really strange part is that if i go look into the dashboard i see all of my images in the blob store data view.

I get this error no matter how i try to get the blob keys out :

> com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter doFilter: 
>   Could not parse multipart message: javax.mail.internet.ParseException:
>   Missing ';'

I am really hung up on this one and i could really use a little help.

EDIT more of the code

the fetch of the blob store url

```
private String fetchUrl()
{
    String url = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/BS/returnKey");
    return url;
}
```

snippit of the return code where the error occurs

```
...
if(inUrl.contains("returnKey"))
{
    Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
...
```

so in my dev environment (the development app server packed in with GAE plugin for eclipse), it works fine, but then after i deploy to the app engine, the same code will not work.
I also tried pulling the data out of the Input stream from the request with teh same results (working on the dev , not on the prod).

thanks to everyone for your help!

Comment: May it be possible that you URL in UploadService or BlobService is wrong? I hade an issue, where my BlobService worked local, but not on GAE. (Maybe a request to localhost)

Comment: You should post some code that does not work for you

Comment: Please post your code so that we can help you.

Comment: Sam, i am using the blobstore to generate the url. im not sure why that would be a problem, but i will check it out to make sure. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that you can not have spaces in the id of the input on the form. I feel like there should be a more obvious error.

In any event i hope that someone finds this useful!